# Mouseleave and Blur jQuery just change content if both are true

Tags: jquery

Hello everyone need some help for my site.

I have a problem with a button on the right side of an input text, I just want to make it auto focus on page load, when the input is focused, when the button value changes (like width, color, orcontent). **I want that when mouseleave or mouseout my div (#centro) AND blur (focusout) input text, button back to original**, and I have another problem when the button reverts back to the original I need some animation, because it just instantly reverts back at the moment.

If someone know how to improve my button I appreciate!

Comment: add fiddle what you have tried ?

Comment: look my site, http://www.kauan.com.br/piratame - Live Real Demo

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```
  $(function () {
    $("#inputselect").focus(function () {
        $("#enviar").replaceWith("<button id='enviar'>" + "Avançado" + "</button>", 1000);
        $("#enviar").animate({
            "width": "136px"
        }, 1000);
        $("#enviar").css({
            "background-color": "#EC0000"
        }, 1000);
    });
    $('#centro').mouseout(function () {
        doAction();
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $("#centro");
        if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            doAction();
        }
    });

    function doAction() {
        $("#enviar").replaceWith("<button id='enviar'>" + "OK" + "</button>", 1000);
        $('#enviar').animate({
            width: '64px'
        }, 1000);
        $("#enviar").css({
            "background-color": "#990000"
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, sorry about my english, but i not want remove focus of input when mouseleave the area, i want button back to normal when my mouse leave area and remove input focus (when i click in other part of the site) like clickout. So i need check two statments so then do the function.

Comment: still ins't working when my mouse out of area (div.centro) my button back to normal, need a operator && (AND) to check two statement at same time so if both return true doaction() EDIT: if you enter in my site and no mouse over div centro and write you can see button still large i want it like first time, but when you mouse over div centro and then mouse out button back to normal without leave inputfocus...